# python selenium click <a> button

Tags: python, selenium, macros

I'm making macro with selenium.

I want to click this button on [this page](http://cafe.daum.net/WekiMeki)

[image]

So, I used following code. but, It does not work.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/section/div/a').click()
```

What code should i use?

Comment: do you get error or what ? Always put error message in question (as text).

Comment: i got error.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/ikedo/git/gdsa.py", line 22, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/section/div/a').click()\
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)

Comment: I will repeate: put  in question (not in comment)

Answer (score 4):

This button is inside `<iframe id="down">` but Selenium treats `frame` as separated page and you have to first `switch_to.frame` before you can search inside frame.

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_id('down')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

And as @match said you could use `id` to search elements. But it works also with your `xpath`

```
import selenium.webdriver

url = 'http://cafe.daum.net/WekiMeki'

driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()
#driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

frame = driver.find_element_by_id('down')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

driver.find_element_by_id('fancafe-widget-cheer').click()

#driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/section/div/a').click()
```

Comment: I tryed that way. but, It doen't be clicked.

Comment: I put full working code and it redirects me to login page. It works even with your `xpath` Do you get any error message ?

Comment: BTW: if doesn't work then you should add more information - ie. error which you get. And maybe you should put in question minimal working code which you use so we could run it to see your problem. You can also add information what system you use. In error I saw path `/Users/` so I guess you use `MacOS`

Answer (score 2):

Using an absolute path like that is risky, since if the site structure changes, it won't work anymore.

Luckily the element you want to click has a unique id: `id="fancafe-widget-cheer"`

So you can select it by doing:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('fancafe-widget-cheer')
```

Comment: I tryed that way. but, It doen't be clicked.